# How to fetch table rows one by one using for loop

Tags: for-loop, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wanted to read all the records of a table one by one using for loop and store its key to some temp variable.
For Example:Employee table consists of Ename, EID as key and Address.
having total of 25 rows. I want to read rows one by one and store its key it in myTemp variable.

Please suggest i had to use Procedure or function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code snippet. Hope it helps!

```
DECLARE
      l_name employees.name%TYPE;
      l_eid employees.eid%TYPE;
    BEGIN
      SELECT name, eid
        INTO l_name, l_eid
        FROM employees e;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_name || ' is identified by ' || l_eid);
    END;
```